# C# OOP of inheritance and polymorphism

Tags: c#

I get a warning in my program that is
'Employee.Salaried.CalculatePay()' hides inherited member 'Employee.Employee.CalculatePay()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
 for this

```
    public double CalculatePay()
    {
        return ((AnnualSalary * (ManagementLevel * BONUS_PERCENT)) + AnnualSalary) / 52;
    }
```

Anyone have suggestions on how to get rid of there warning?

```
    public double CalculatePay()
    {
        return annualSalary / 52;
    }

    public double CalculatePay(double modifiedSalary)
    {
        AnnualSalary = modifiedSalary;
        return AnnualSalary / 52;
    }
```

Comment: you should show also the line which calls `CalculatePay()`

Comment: use `override` keyword

Comment: Please dont ask the same question twice, if your question doesn't get enough attention the way to solve that is by earning points and putting a bounty on it. Or do some research, most compiler warnings are well documented. Good luck!

Comment: @JeremyThompson Jess did not ask the same question twice, he edited his old accepted question to be a new question. I rolled back the old question (and edited it to be a more accurate title), it is nolonger a duplicate. **HOWEVER** if this question was reopened, i would vote to close it for not showing minimal effort to solve the problem first.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid this you would have to change the code to something like

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void TADA()
    {

    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void TADA()
    {

    }
}
```

Have a look at

[virtual (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The virtual keyword is used to modify a method, property, indexer, or
>   event declaration and allow for it to be overridden in a derived
>   class.
>
> When a virtual method is invoked, the run-time type of the object is
>   checked for an overriding member. The overriding member in the most
>   derived class is called, which might be the original member, if no
>   derived class has overridden the member.
>
> By default, methods are non-virtual. You cannot override a non-virtual
>   method.

[override (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx)

> The override modifier is required to extend or modify the abstract or
>   virtual implementation of an inherited method, property, indexer, or
>   event.

Answer (score 0):

seems the parent class (or the parent of it) already has a same function CalculatePay(), so if you want to overwrite it, just declare your function as override:

```
public override double CalculatePay()
{
    return ((AnnualSalary * (ManagementLevel * BONUS_PERCENT)) + AnnualSalary) / 52;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding the `CalculatePay()` function of your base class. If this is what you are looking to do, use the `new` modifier to change your code to:

```
new public double CalculatePay()
{
    return ((AnnualSalary * (ManagementLevel * BONUS_PERCENT)) + AnnualSalary) / 52;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the way to get rid of the warning